# How can I run a class from alert rules in axapta

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Hi everybody I want to create alert rule in axapta. But some class will run when rules run. I want that class to work with the new rule. How can I do this?

Comment: I couldn't try anything cause I didn't find where is class or method insert on eventrule table from eventcreaterule form

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom event action and call your logic there.

Class representing an action must inherit from the `EventAction` Class, and it must implement the `execute` method. For each event rule, the Alerts module creates a list of action class IDs that must be instantiated. The individual `execute` method that is associated with each respective class ID is called whenever a rule matches an event. The list of actions is customizable. For more information, see
[How to: Add Custom Actions for Alerts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa624189.aspx)